# Pandas DataFrame / HDFStore Pass Multiple Date formats through CSV

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I am doing the following to pass multiple dates in different columns. However, the second column ( time ) column doesn't conform to this string so it has errors. How do i achieve this?

```
 dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

 for chunk in pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=500000, parse_dates=['date','time'], parse_dates = dateparse, names = col_names, index_col = index_cols, header = 0, dtype = dtype)
        store.append('df',chunk)
```

Sample Data :

```
 Date                     Time
19/10/2016 00:00:00      00:05:01
```

Comment: Have you tried simply leaving out the `parse_dates = dateparse` part and specifying `parse_dates=[['date', 'time']]`, which will combine the date and time into one column?

Comment: It would be better if you posted sample data as the raw CSV (open in a text editor and copy-paste from there).

Comment: I guess you have two options here - either add date part to the `Time` column and convert it to `datetime` or convert it to `timedelta64[ns]` dtype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to specify datetime format if you have a standard format like `'19/10/2016 00:00:00'` - Pandas will parse it automatically, so you don't need to use `date_parser` parameter.

**Option 1:** Converting `Time` column to `datetime64[ns]` dtype:

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=500000, parse_dates=['Date'], names=col_names, index_col=index_cols, dtype = dtype):
    chunk['Time'] = chunk['Date'].dt.normalize() + pd.to_timedelta(chunk['Time'])
    store.append('df',chunk)
```

**Option 2:** Converting `Time` column to `timedelta64[ns]` dtype:

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=500000, parse_dates=['Date'], names=col_names, index_col=index_cols, dtype = dtype):
    chunk['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(chunk['Time'])
    store.append('df',chunk)
```

PS both mentioned dtypes are supported by HDFStore

**Option 3:**

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=500000, names=col_names, index_col=index_cols, dtype = dtype):
    chunk['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(chunk['Date'], errors='coerce')
    chunk['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(chunk['Time'], errors='coerce')
    store.append('df',chunk)
```

Comment: Thanks MaxU. The reason i wanted to parse the values explicitly is because this data is user entered and tehrefore prone to error. If i dont explicitly parse it and there is an error in the date / time columns this would become objects? And then if i try to add the next chunk with clean data / new CSV into the same store this again becomes a problem. That is why i wanted to clarify explicitly state this?

Comment: @CodeGeek123, in this you may want to go for "Option 3" (see update in the answer)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can tell Pandas to combine the date and time columns into one column by passing a list of lists instead of just a list in `parse_dates` as specified in [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> **parse_dates** : boolean or list of ints or names or list of lists or dict, default False
>
> - boolean. If True -> try parsing the index.
> - list of ints or names. e.g. If [1, 2, 3] -> try parsing columns 1, 2, 3 each as a separate date column.
> - list of lists. e.g. If [[1, 3]] -> combine columns 1 and 3 and parse as
>     a single date column.
>     dict, e.g. {‘foo’ : [1, 3]} -> parse columns 1, 3 as date and call result ‘foo’

You'll also want to specify `dayfirst=True` given your date format.

That means your code becomes

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=500000, 
                         parse_dates=[['date', 'time']],  # note the extra []
                         dayfirst=True,
                         names=col_names, index_col=index_cols, 
                         header=0, dtype=dtype)
    store.append('df',chunk)
```